# xsl-fo: Two reports en parallel, one in odd pages another in even pages

Tags: xsl-fo

I want to generate a PDF having one content flow in odd pages and another in even pages, so when you print the PDF double sided you have a template to write notes even pages. This is what I have but it does not work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <!-- Odd Pages -->
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="odd" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm">
                <fo:region-body region-name="body-odd" margin-top="118mm" margin-bottom="50mm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="headerodd" extent="116mm"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="footerodd" extent="48mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <!-- Even Pages -->
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="even" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm">
                <fo:region-body region-name="body-even" margin-top="118mm" margin-bottom="50mm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="headereven" extent="116mm"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="footereven" extent="48mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="A4">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="odd" blank-or-not-blank="any" odd-or-even="odd"/>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="even" blank-or-not-blank="any" odd-or-even="even"/>
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="body-odd">
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
            <fo:flow flow-name="body-even">
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an EVEN page. Back-page report 2
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an EVEN page. Back-page report 2
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block page-break-after="always">
                    This is an EVEN page. Back-page report 2
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
```

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? What are the symptoms?

Comment: The problem is that It first generates six pages with odd pages having the right text and the other even pages blank, then it prints another six pages with three blank odd pages and the others odd ones with the right text. That's is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Put the static content for the notes pages in an `fo:static-content` that is directed to the `fo:region-before` (or any of the other outer regions) of the even page:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="headereven">
    <fo:block>
      This is an EVEN page. Back-page report 2
    </fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:flow flow-name="body-odd">
    <fo:block page-break-after="always">
      This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-after="always">
      This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-after="always">
      This is an ODD page. Front-page report 1.
    </fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

This way, you don't need to have exactly the right number of pages worth of note content to match your real content.

You can position the content so that it shows up at the correct position on the page.  If you direct the static content to `fo:region-before`, you shouldn't have to worry about using the correct extent since any content that overflows the region will remain visible by default.

Comment: The "static content" is not really "static", it is like another output, even though each page is going to be similar there is going to be pre-filled with information from an input XML file, for instance it will have a different person name, address, some facts, etc. Each person will have a page. Can I achieve that with an fo:static-content ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  The only way to get different static content on each page is to use a different `fo:simple-page-master` with an `fo:region-before` with a different `region-name` value and to have a separate `fo:static-content` for each `fo:region-before`.  If you really are doing manual page breaks for your content, the simplest solution might be just to interleave the odd-page and even-page content and rely an the page breaks to put everything on the correct pages.

Comment: Actually, you could get different content into the `fo:region-before` by using markers, but the `fo:marker` would have to be from your `fo:flow`, and I don't know enough about your data to know how you'd arrange that.