# original text on left side with facing translation on the right

Tags: xsl-fo

I would like to produce a pdf with XSL-FO of a text which has a translation facing the main text, so that on left pages I have the original text and on the right pages the translation. 
How would I do that? I have tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876221/xsl-fo-two-reports-en-parallel-one-in-odd-pages-another-in-even-pages) but I had no success, it works only if the content does not have to go to the next page and the same issue raised there remains true for me.
Is there any way to achieve this and have two parallel flows?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible in XSL-FO; you can not manage text flows "alternating" on page the way you want.

Comment: If you want them "synced" -- meaning something like matching headings and paragraphs then I have done before by using a table with two columns. Putting content in each cell, left and right down the table. Using keep conditions if possible and you can then match what is on left and what is on right. Of course, this assumes that the documents have identical structure and do not differ (like the translation has three para's but the source has two).

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, generate your XSL-FO for the translation and the main text as a two-column table (or three-column, with the center column for avoiding the gutter).

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use the `axf:spread-page-master` extension (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf65/ahf-spread.html) and flow the content into an `fo:spread-region` that spans both pages of the spread.  Job done.

If you are not using AH Formatter, then you want separate `fo:simple-page-master` for the left-hand and right-hand pages.  The `fo:region-body` in each needs to have a different `region-name`.  Both `fo:region-body` need to be wide enough for the width of a regular `fo:region-body` (what you'd use if you weren't faking things) plus the gutter margins for both pages, plus the width of (what will look like) the regular `fo:region-body` on the facing page.

In the `fo:region-body` for the left-hand page, set the `margin-right` to a negative value equal to the two gutter widths plus the nominal width of the opposite `fo:region-body`.  Do similarly for the `margin-left` of the right-hand page's `fo:region-body`.

In your `fo:page-sequence`, generate two `fo:flow` that each have a copy of your content.  Direct one to the `fo:region-body` on the left-hand page, and direct the other to the `fo:region-body` on the right-hand page.

All being well, you'll be able to format two copies of your content with identical line and page breaks.  Because the content that overflows the page isn't visible, it will look like just one version of your content.

Unless you do more work, you will have ruined the accessibility of your document, since a screen-reader would want to read both copies of your content.  You will also have done terrible things to your accessibility by putting everything in a table to begin with.

If your content includes IDs, then you need to make sure that you generate only one of each ID and that it's on the version of the FO that will be visible if a user jumped to that page.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I have tried this out and I was not able to reproduce it. I am not using AH Formatter, but I also cannot generate two fo:flow inside a fo:page-sequence, and with two fo:page-sequence the overlapping does not happen. is then the AH Formatter the only option?